# Variables set in the constructor are forgotten?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

What I'm trying to do here is first to create the variable **$sql_info** and set it to a default value, then the constructor takes one argument, which it will then set to the **$sql_info** variable. If I do `echo $sql_info;` inside the constructor it all works fine, but if I try to do it in an a different function, it doesn't echo anything to the screen, not even the default value. Why is that?

```
<?php

class Connection {

    private $sql_info = "default";
    function __construct($Info) {

        //Set new value of $sql_info
        $sql_info = $Info;
    }

    function Connect() {
        global $sql_info;

        //echo the newly set string
        echo $sql_info;
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$this->sql_info`?

Comment: Oh wow, it was that simple? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to write `$this`!

Try this:

```
<?php

    class Connection {

        private $sql_info = "default";

        function __construct($Info) {

            //Set new value of $sql_info
            $this->sql_info = $Info;
        }

        function Connect() {
            global $sql_info;

            //echo the newly set string
            echo $this->sql_info;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the class variable using the "this" keyword. It is declared as a private variable in your code.